# ANOVA with blocking question

Tags: anova, blocking

An ANOVA analysis is done on the quality of pizza in two settings:

1. pan vs. no pan while blocking on pizza brands,
2. one brand vs. the other while blocking on using a pan or not.

[image]

Will the F-statistics change for Pan and Brand across the two settings?

I just don't understand how the blocking would work in this scenario. Can someone demonstrate how you would group pizza ratings in both settings?